# CentOS Spam Troubleshot

Tags: email, centos, spam, spam-prevention, exim

I am having a problem in my server. It's sending a lot of spam emails out. I am using Exim, and i did all the possible Tweaks from WHM to prevent spamming. I already tried to find the source of these email, from what script they are coming from.

I tried with `TCPdum` and `netstat`.

The emails are going out from some cPanel user for example user1@servername.sdm.com (the server host name) not from user@samedomain.com.

Any idea or suggestion what can i check?

Answer (score 0):

I already found the problem. I was monitoring with TCP dump the connections in port 25 and grepped the account what was spamming than i found what script was sending the emails by monitoring the Exim logs.